# How can I create multiple checkboxes next to each other?

Tags: formatting, hyperref

[image]

I have been able to create interactive checkboxes using the following code by using the `\CheckBox{....}\\`

However I'm currently stuck and can't figure out to create multiple boxes next to each other, like the image attached. 
I would appreciate your help very much!

```
\documentclass[11Pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,wasysym}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{ATA-27}

\fancyhead[RE,LO]{Acceptance Test Manual}

\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{xxx}

\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{Page \thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\title{A320 Acceptance Test Manual (ATM)\ ATA 27 - Flight Controls}

\author{Parsa Shamsi}

\date{\today}

\maketitle

\break

\tableofcontents

\break

\begin{Form}

\section{On Ground}

\subsection{Indications}

\textbf{Set GREEN HYD SYS OFF:}\\

\CheckBox{Confirm Spoilers 1 and 5 are unavailable: }\\

\CheckBox{Confirm L and R GREEN SYS AIL are unavailable: }\\

\CheckBox{Confirm L inner ELEV is unavailable: }\\

\CheckBox{Confirm RUDDER GREEN SYS is unavailable: }\\

\section{In Flight}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Should the boxes be interactive? And, if so, what should be the action?

Comment: It is hard to make comments on such a small fragment of code but you show `\\ ` which is a forced line break, ig you want the boxes next to each other just don't use `\\ `

Comment: I'm sorry for the little amount of code. I have added my entire code to this comment. The boxes should indeed be interactive. I should be able to select a box for a passing result and a box for a failing result.

Comment: Outside of specific contexts (such as `tabular`s), you probably should have almost no `\\ ` in your `.tex` file.  If you find you are writing `\\ ` frequently, you should probably read some introductory manuals before proceeding.

Comment: I have added all of my code to the question section. As you can see I have been using \\ to separate the sentences which are different consequences of an action. Since the consequence of an action is either a passing result or a failing result, I need two boxes next to each other. However I have only managed to display one box per sentence (which is one consequence)

Comment: As others have said, you shouldn't be using `\\ ` anyway, but you certainly should have neither `\\ ` nor a blank line between check boxes which you want to end up adjacent to each other. The first forces a line break in a bad way. The second inserts a paragraph break in a good way, but only if you actually want a new paragraph.

Comment: Your code gives me 5 warnings about bad boxes where TeX can't find a good way to typeset the page in accordance with your instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method which demonstrates two different approaches: one uses a `tabular` and the other not.

The code:

- fixes the order of package loading to put `hyperref` last`;
- eliminates inconsistent layout by reading the console and using `geometry` with the value `fancyhdr` provides for `headheight`;
- demonstrates how to avoid TeX's complaints about bad boxes while inserting additional spacing for the existing examples;
- provides examples of multiple check boxes in ordinary text;
- provides an example using a `tabular` for alignment.

The solution uses `array` and `booktabs` for formatting the `tabular` example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,booktabs,array}
\usepackage[headheight=14pt]{geometry}% read the console - fandyhdr tells you what value you need for consistent layout!
\usepackage{hyperref}% load last unless you know a package should be loaded later

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{ATA-27}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{Acceptance Test Manual}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{xxx}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\begin{document}
\title{A320 Acceptance Test Manual (ATM)\ ATA 27 - Flight Controls}
\author{Parsa Shamsi}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\break

\tableofcontents
\break

\begin{Form}
  \section{On Ground}

  \subsection{Indications}

  \textbf{Set GREEN HYD SYS OFF:}\bigskip

  \CheckBox{Confirm Spoilers 1 and 5 are unavailable: }\bigskip

  \CheckBox{Confirm L and R GREEN SYS AIL are unavailable: }\bigskip

  \CheckBox{Confirm L inner ELEV is unavailable: }\bigskip

  \CheckBox{Confirm RUDDER GREEN SYS is unavailable: }\bigskip

  \section{In Flight}

  Does this pass or fail? \CheckBox{ } \CheckBox{ } \CheckBox{ } \CheckBox{ }\bigskip

  And this?  \CheckBox{ } \CheckBox{ } \CheckBox{ } \CheckBox{ }\bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3.5em}}c@{}}

    \toprule
      & Pass & Fail & Unclear & N/A\\
    \midrule
    Test 1  & \CheckBox{ } & \CheckBox{ } & \CheckBox{ } & \CheckBox{ } &\\[1ex]
    Test 2  & \CheckBox{ } & \CheckBox{ } & \CheckBox{ } & \CheckBox{ } &\\[1ex]
    Test 3  & \CheckBox{ } & \CheckBox{ } & \CheckBox{ } & \CheckBox{ } &\\[1ex]
    Test 4  & \CheckBox{ } & \CheckBox{ } & \CheckBox{ } & \CheckBox{ } &\\[1ex]
    Test 5  & \CheckBox{ } & \CheckBox{ } & \CheckBox{ } & \CheckBox{ } &\\[1ex]
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image: multiply boxes]

Comment: @ParsaShamsi You're welcome! Note that if you use a tabular, I found I needed a dummy column at the end to avoid the boxes coming out strangely. I wasn't not sure how else to avoid this, so I went with the empty column.

Comment: I was indeed wondering what the reason was for the extra column. Thanks for explaining that.  I have been implementing your code for the last few minutes and  it works great. Everything remains aligned perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You might try something like one of these (note: I have simplified your original `.tex` file):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}% note the change from 11Pt to 11pt
\usepackage{hyperref,wasysym,array}
% Not needed for minimal working example (MWE):
% \usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \pagestyle{fancy}
% \fancyhf{}
% \fancyhead[LE,RO]{ATA-27}
% \fancyhead[RE,LO]{Acceptance Test Manual}
% \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{xxx}
% \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{Page \thepage}
% \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
% \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\newcommand\dblbox[1]{%
\addvspace{\baselineskip}%
\CheckBox{#1:~}\hspace{0.5em}\CheckBox{}}

\newcommand\tblbox[1]{%
#1: & \CheckBox{}\hspace{0.5em}\CheckBox{}\tabularnewline}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

\section{On Ground}

\subsection{Indications}

\textbf{Set GREEN HYD SYS OFF:}

\dblbox{Confirm Spoilers 1 and 5 are unavailable}

\dblbox{Confirm L and R GREEN SYS AIL are unavailable}

\dblbox{Confirm L inner ELEV is unavailable}

\dblbox{Confirm RUDDER GREEN SYS is unavailable}


\section{Or in a Table}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedleft}p{3cm}}

\tblbox{Confirm Spoilers 1 and 5 are unavailable}

\tblbox{Confirm L and R GREEN SYS AIL are unavailable}

\tblbox{Confirm L inner ELEV is unavailable}

\tblbox{Confirm RUDDER GREEN SYS is unavailable}

\end{tabular}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to make it work with the following code: 
"Confirm Spoilers 1 and 5 are unavailable: \CheckBox{Pass}\CheckBox{ Fail }\\"

But the your method is much cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: @ParsaShamsi -- glad it works for you!